# Ethernet packets data

Tags: freebsd, ethernet, packet

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDyPI.png)

I would like to know what does these parts below mean.

What is 0010

What does the 08 00 27 d5... mean

What does the data on the right mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0000:`, `0010:`… indicates the indexes in your frame in hexadecimal. Since each line contains 16 bytes (10 in hexadecimal), the indexes increase 10 by 10.

The `08 00 27 d5 …` is the content of your Ethernet frame. Byte per bytes. The 6 first bytes are the Ethernet destination address. The 6 next ones, the Ethernet source address. The 2 next ones (`08 00`) indicates the type of the frame (here IPv4), then there is the content of the IPv4 dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The symbols with the dots in the right what do they mean?

Comment: The symbols are the ASCII character associated with each byte. Dots are used to fill non ASCII characters (or control characters). They may be useful to print DNS request for example where ASCII chars are meaningful.